# Launch macOS app from FinderSync extension

Tags: swift, macos, finder, findersync

I wrote an app that implements FinderSync extension.

Everything works fine, I can "communicate" by sending notifications through `DistributedNotificationCenter` from extension to main app. But obviously it works if the main app is running only.

Is there any mechanism to open terminated app and pass parameters?

**UPDATE:**

The idea is to implement simple image processing app. I want to run the main app (containing execution code and GUI) from Finder-Sync extension.

To be more specific I implemented `func menu(for menu: FIMenuKind) -> NSMenu?` of `FIFinderSyncProtocol` and I want to run/open main app when user right-clicks the menu item and selects operation I added into menu.

Comment: You might want to consider implementing background app refresh. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/scenes/preparing_your_ui_to_run_in_the_background/updating_your_app_with_background_app_refresh

Comment: @otolock I updated question to describe my idea better

Comment: You've tried to launch with URL? I am aware that it works with the share extension, haven't checked for Finder extension.

Comment: @IvanIčin Do you have experience with passing multiple selected files using URL? Are there any limits?

Comment: @MartinPilch my idea was just to launch the app and then communicate as you already do, or make some changes like to notify back that the app has started and send the message then. I am not sure if there are limitations in URL length, probably there are.

Comment: @otolock this is macOS, not iOS.

Comment: @MartinPilch How did you manage to "communicate" your app and finder extension? I've tried everything and cannot find an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74778974/how-to-send-and-receive-notifications-from-finder-extension-to-swiftui-app would appreciate some help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I guess that my comment is at least somewhat valid, I'll put it in the answer.

Extensions allow launching of the main app by using the URL that app handles.

Communication with URL may not be enough, but you can have the app group where extension could write the data to disk and be readable by the main app or use your current way of communication with some adaptations to this method.

Comment: Thanks! I've made it. Now I need to figure out the best way how to pass selected items from, Finder Sync extension to my main app but that's other problem (experimenting with DistributeNotificationCenter at the moment)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SMLoginItemSetEnabled` to launch background "helper" application.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/servicemanagement/1501557-smloginitemsetenabled

This helper app can be launched in the background by a sandboxed app with few restrictions, and kept open when then main app closes. Your FinderSync extension can continue to communicate with the helper app even if the main app is closed.